# screenshot now using $HOME not $HOME/Pictures

Tags: directory, gnome-shell, screenshot, gnome-screenshot

When I hit 'Print Scrn' my screenshots are in $HOME.  I want to move them back tp ~/Pictures/.  All online help says do this or that, some of it pretty scary, and much of it does nothing.  Some say it is gnome-shell's fault.  Some say it is a known bug, but it was working for me not that long ago.  Some say just set it in the dialog, but I do not get such a dialog.i

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? I just took a screenshot using Alt+PrintScreen and it went to `~/Pictures` in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I have 18.04.3 LTS but it has been unhappy lately, crashing much, and once my / and so all went read-only on me, which may have caused it to fall back from ~/Pictures to ~.  I verified all my file systems from a usb trial boot.

Comment: I am running 18.04.3 on 2 computers. Both are stable.

Answer (score 0):

Install `dconf-editor` and run it.

Go to `/ org / gnome / gnome-screenshot`
Click in `auto-save-directory`. Disable `Use default value`.

Add your desired folder in the text box, i.e. `~/Pictures`

Hope this is what you want

Comment: It should not be necessary to change that key, which by default is set to an empty string. It probably disables the save dialog in interactive mode. Although this might be OK for the OP, I would rather suggest changing the key org.gnome.gnome-screenshot last-save-directory. One could also change that by using the program interactively, i.e., "gnome-screenshot -i" and specifying the desired folder in the second step.

Comment: Nice tip, but it does say ~/Pictures already.  However, use default value was off. however, the custom value was also ~/Pictures, so I guess we are within control of "the bug".  I set it to use default and it promised to change it when I left the view, but still it is using $HOME.  I will reboot and see if it takes on restart!

Comment: No, after reboot it is still using $HOME.  Maybe I will reinstall 18.04.3 and try not to corrupt it this time!  It's just a pain to reinstall all my apps without munging the OS up, especially the ttf.